# How to change decimal points on chart label and change the label position?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, label

I made a chart using `ggplot2` that shows me some historical data:

```
library(ggplot2)
chart_2 <- ggplot(graf2, aes(x=data, y=relativo, label = as.integer(relativo))) + 
scale_fill_discrete(guide = F) +
geom_line(aes(y=relativo, color="red"), size = 0.7) +
labs(title = "Relativo Preço Gasolina: Consumidor/Distribuidora", x = "Data", y="Relativo de Preços") +
theme_bw() +
theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 12, face = "bold"), 
axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5, size = 10, color = "black"), 
axis.title=element_text(size = 12)) +
scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "1.5 years") +
geom_dl(aes(label=last(relativo)), vjust = -2, method="last.points")
```

[image]

I have two problems here:

1. I want to change the position of the label in the last point of the chart, but I don't know how.
2. The label has a lot of decimal points, I want to change to just 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "The label has a lot of decimal points, I want to change to just 2"?

Comment: the number in the label is something as: 1.129865665 and I want to be 1.13, got it?

Comment: Create a new variable with numbers rounded as you want them, and use that as labelling variable. Use `round()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To change position of the label adjust argument `position` using `position_nudge`:

   ```
   # Using -2 only as example to move label along x-axis
   geom_dl(aes(label = last(relativo)), 
           method = "last.points",
           position = position_nudge(-2))
   ```
2. To change to two decimal points use [`round` function from `base` R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/Round):

   ```
    round(last(relativo), 2)
   ```

Combined code should be:

```
geom_dl(aes(label = round(last(relativo), 2), 
        method = "last.points",
        position = position_nudge(-2))
```

PS.: I don't know what your function `last` does (couldn't test my code).

Comment: the last function get the last value of the column "relativo" from my data.frame. it worked well, thanks!

Comment: @DaniloImbimbo happy to help! I also learned something new :-)